# Как в произвольной таксономии вывести посты категорий исключающие предыдущие?

Tags: php, wordpress

На wordpress-сайте создан произвольный тип поста объявлений. В зависимости от их категории `ad_cat` выводятся объявления на соответствующих страницах

В категории дисков - вот так:

```
query_posts( array( 'post_type' => APP_POST_TYPE,
'paged' => get_query_var('paged'), 'ad_cat' => 'disks', 'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1 ) );
```

В категории шин - вот так:

```
query_posts( array( 'post_type' => APP_POST_TYPE,
'paged' => get_query_var('paged'), 'ad_cat' => 'shiny', 'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1 ) );
```

Теперь осталось вывести на отдельную страницу все оставшиеся объявления, не входящие в предыдущие категории (диски, шины). Пытаюсь это настроить при помощи [инструкции](https://wp-kama.ru/function/query_posts), но на выходе получаю совсем не то, что ожидаю..

```
query_posts( array( 'tax_query' => array( 'taxonomy' => APP_POST_TYPE,
'field' => 'ad_cat','terms' => array( 'disks', 'shiny' ),'operator' => '!='), 
'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,'paged' => get_query_var('paged') ));
```

Как исправить?

Comment: Упорно не желаем идти правильным путём? Даже ссылка в вопросе об этом говорит. Нда..

Comment: @SeVlad в смысле? не увидел в вашей фразе помощи по решению

Comment: https://wp-kama.ru/function/query_posts#vazhno-ispolzovat-query_posts-mozhet-byt-opasno https://wpmag.ru/2014/query_posts-wordpress/

Comment: @SeVlad сколько ни бился-старался, альтернативы у меня не сработали и не выводили контент так, как нужно. плюнул и оставил работающую версию с `query_posts`. Здесь вопрос у меня совершенно не про то использовать ее или нет, а как вывести категории, которые не использовались на предыдущих страницах

Comment: Вася, я вот что пытаюсь донести... Лично я, как только  вижу `query_posts` - всё! Ступор (опуская маты). Остальной текст ни глаз ни моск не воспринимает. Напрочь отказывается даже задуматься об помощи в  опасных решениях. Так понятнее?

Comment: @SeVlad понятнее.. но, даже в мануале написано, что использовать `query_posts` можно, если только с большой осторожностью, очищая инфу при запросе по ее окончании и т.п. Это как раз мой случай - сколько ни тестировал, все работает как часы. В моем случае, конечно же, можно соорудить костыль - пройтись по всем остальным категориям вручную, но хотелось бы при добавлении новых категорий не лезть каждый раз в код за исправлениями

Comment: нет такого оператора `!=`, надо поставить `'operator' => 'NOT IN'`

Comment: @KAGG Design вообще-то есть и отлично себя проявляет. Читайте внимательно кодекс или мануал https://wp-kama.ru/function/query_posts
`compare — каким оператором производить сравнение. Может быть: =, !=, >, >=, <, <=, IN, NOT IN, BETWEEN, NOT BETWEEN.`

Comment: Согласно именно этому мануалу, такой оператор есть в meta_query, но не в tax_query

Comment: то же самое написано в codex https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query читайте внимательно: `operator (string) - Operator to test. Possible values are 'IN', 'NOT IN', 'AND', 'EXISTS' and 'NOT EXISTS'. Default value is 'IN'`.